# Как удалить элементы из std::list<std::pair<>>;

Tags: c++, list, stl, функтор

Помогите удалить элементы из std::list>;

Следующий код:

```
class A
{
//
};
class C
{
//
};
using B = std::function<void(C&, const sf::Event &)>;

std::list<std::pair<A, B>> leres;
int main()
{
    for (auto itr = leres.begin(); itr != leres.end(); ++itr)
    {
        leres.remove(*itr);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Не компилируется. 
Ошибка:
**error C2678: бинарный "==": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "const _Ty1" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)
1>        with**

Comment: Вам нужно определить bool operator ==(const pair<A, B>&, const pair<A, B>&), а также внимательно читать ответ от  Harry(особенно про erase().

Comment: если пользоваться erase то оператор сравнения не нужен я правильно понимаю?

Comment: да, верно. И  учтите, что после первого удаления итератор станет не действительным

Comment: В итоге сравниваются элементы, а  элементами списка являются пары. Для пар есть оператор ==( Т.е. если А1 == A2 && B1 == B2 то pair<A, B>(A1, B1) == pair<A, B>(A2, B2)). Если у вас нет этого оператора для каждого элемента пары, то должен быть оператор == для пар.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас нет операторов `==` для `A` и `B`, соответственно, нет такового и для `pair<A,B>`, так что операция `remove()`, которая должна сравнивать каждый элемент с указанным значением, делать это не в состоянии.

Воспользуйтесь для удаления конкретного элемента по итератору функцией [`erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase). Нет никакого смысла, получив итератор, превращать его в значение и вновь выполнять поиск - уже в `remove`.

Но, похоже, вы просто хотите удалить в цикле все элементы, полностью очистив список, нет? Если да - вызовите `leres.clear()` и не мучайтесь...

*Update*

Изменения в вопрос внесли ничего нового. В любом случае требуется сравнение элементов в  списке. Т.е. пар. Которое в общем случае выполняется путем сравнения элементов. Можно просто написать свой компаратор для сравнения элементов (пар) и передать его в список при создании.

Даю пару решений (тела операторов, понятно, не более чем заглушки).

```
class A
{
};
class B
{
};

bool operator==(const A&,const A&) { return true; }
bool operator==(const B&,const B&) { return true; }

std::list<std::pair<A, B>> leres;
int main()
{

    leres.remove(*leres.begin());
}
```

или

```
class A
{
};
class B
{
};

bool operator==(const pair<A,B>&,const pair<A,B>&) { return true; }

std::list<std::pair<A, B>> leres;
int main()
{

    leres.remove(*leres.begin());
}
```

Comment: Нет, по идее хочу удалить один элемент. Например создать ссылку на него std::pair<A,B> &ref= *itr; leres.remove(ref);

Comment: На самом деле оператор присваивания для класса A присутствует. А B это не класс а std::function<void(C&, const sf::Event &)>. Как быть в таком случае?Нужно создать оператор сравнения для класса C?

Comment: тогда для чего цикл?

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, для демонстрации упрощенного варианта кода.

Comment: Лучше вопрос задавать на примере реального кода, чем потом давать разьяснения по поводу того, что вам нужно...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, прошу прощения. Исправил.

Comment: @Harry, в вопросе были внесены изменения

Comment: @ARHovsepyan См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: *На самом деле оператор присваивания для класса A присутствует* `==` - оператор сравнения, а не присвоения. Ну, а если B  - функциональный тип, то что ж? сравнивайте эквивалентность функциональных объектов. В конце-концов, грубо говоря, синус не равен косинусу - это же тоже сравнение :)